When do the Mythbusters appear in the Phineas and Ferb Star Wars special?
According to CNET, USA Today, and The Hollywood Reporter, the hosts of Mythbusters Adam Savage and Jamie Hyneman make cameo appearances in the Phineas and Ferb Star Wars special as Imperial Stormtroopers. I watched the episode but don't remember hearing their voices.
When do Adam Savage and Jamie Hyneman appear in the Phineas and Ferb Star Wars special?

Adam Savage and Jamie Hyneman as Office Stormtroopers - wiki

That is not a crossover I'd ever have predicted.

@Criggie, um actually, it isn't a crossover.  It is a cameo.  They are famous celebs showing up quickly in another property.  But they don't play themselves, nor do they do anything 'Mythbusters' like.

Quite early on:



1:39
First troopers you see, TK-582 and another un-named one:

Office Stormtrooper #1 : TK-582, I'm gonna need you to run these numbers again.


Office Stormtrooper #2  : I took a third out of the budget already.


Office Stormtrooper #1 : Orders from the top. There's nothing I can do.



https://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/tv-shows/Phineas-and-Ferb-Star-Wars/Office-Stormtroopers/

Office Stormtroopers
Adam Savage, Jamie Hyneman are the voices of Office Stormtroopers in Phineas and Ferb: Star Wars.

IMDB had them listed as Office Stormtrooper #1 and Office Stormtrooper #2

Mythbusters Adam Savage and Jamie Hyneman (who it’s worth noting did special effects on the Star Wars movies and had their own Star Wars crossover episode earlier this year) also play a pair of stormtroopers in the Imperial Administration Offices Star Destroyer.

https://bigshinyrobot.com/star-wars/phineas-and-ferb-star-wars-best-crossover-ever/

https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Gallery:Phineas_and_Ferb:_Star_Wars

